# How to extract data using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Here is the R code:

```
 
output:
character(0)
```

Comment: What does `.a` mean? Your selector is incorrect.

Comment: yes, I thought that's the css selector. I also tried with "a'' without a dot before, but it gives different output not related to the names of the airlines. I'm not sure which selector should I use. I used the "inspect" function to find the selector and for the names of the airlines it suggests 'a' selector. I also tried other selectors like: ''td.notranslate" and "notranslate'', but again the same happens, character(0)

Comment: The web site explicitely forbids web scraping: "Please note that scraping or any other form of automatic data download is in violation of our Terms of Service (https://www.flightradar24.com/terms-and-conditions) and may result in lost access to Flightradar24." So, most likely your request is just being blocked by the server. It could be possible to to circumvent the block by setting a user agent. But I cannot recommend doing that.

Comment: This scraping is for educational purposes. It's not something that's going to be published, sold, used for commercial purpose or something like that. If you can help me learn how to do it, please help. Otherwise it's easiest to say the terms and conditions don't allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CSS Selector so I use XPath instead.

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines'
airline_names <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//td[@class='notranslate']/a") %>% html_text()
```

Hope you can read the code to get the idea.

Comment: Thank you Tri X. That's very helpful. I'll have to learn about the XPath approach too.

Comment: While the approach is correct, the problem is not with the selector, but rather with `read_html` being unable to parse the page correctly.

Comment: @Reserach1Reserach2 You can learn XPath here: http://www.zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html

Comment: @TríX Oh it did work! Somehow it didn't work correctly when I tried it the first time. +1

Comment: Thank you @TriX Your answer was great, practical and useful to learn from it. I will learn more about it from the source that you recommended. If you have a source also where I can learn how to use CSS selector approach in addition, that would be welcome also.

Comment: @Reserach1Reserach2 W3School tutorial looks good to me: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: But I tried the CSS approach too, it didn't work and idk why too.